# Authentication & Authorization in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, authentication, permissions, accessibility

User Steven has the Active Directory account however his profile is not yet populated into SSP User profiles.

NT Authenticated users have the access permission on "Shared Documents - Document Library".

So, will Steven be able to access the "Shared Documents"?

I guess, IIS will authenticate the user Steven to access the "Shared Documents" and SharePoint will authorize the user to View the items in "Shared Documents", is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Users can access sharepoint without a SSP profile.